# Oral sex and semen swallowing

Tags: karma, ethics, sexuality, killing, sexual-misconduct

My girlfriend does oral sex and she likes to swallow my sperm during sex. Will these activities violate any precep?

Will swallowing of semen violate the no killing precet and are sperm cells considered sentient beings?

I would prefer simple answers since I have a little understanding of Buddhism as this point.

Answer (score 3):

Sperm are not considered 'sentient beings' (Mahayana) or 'breathing beings' (Theravada). Therefore, the ejaculation of sperm is not killing in relation to the 1st Buddhist precept.

While it is not a *literal* violation, having a girlfriend without long term commitment violates the *spirit* of the 3rd Buddhist precept. The 3rd precept in Buddhism was taught together with the instruction to parents to ensure the marriage of their children when their children become sexually mature. Therefore, when the 3rd precept refers to a girl '*under the protection of her family*', it means the girl is protected by her family until her family ensures she is married.

If your girlfriend lives with her parents and your having sex with your girlfriend is against the wishes of her parents, this is violating the 3rd precept.

if your girlfriend's parents agree to you & your girlfriend having sex, this does not literally break the precept; even though having sex without long term commitment violates the spirit of the Buddhist teachings because it is not compassionate.

Answer (score 2):

Western culture contradicts alot with respect to traditional eastern culture. At the time of Lord Buddha, celibacy was practiced with couples until marriage (it is still practiced in the present albeit not so commonly), which brings us to the 3rd precept of 'Abstaining from sexual misconduct' (mostly is translated to abstaining from adultery) but sexual acts before marriage does taint (doesn't exactly violate) the 3rd precept as your partner is still under the protection of his/her parents or siblings.

When it comes to the 1st Precept and your question, I believe as sperm doesn't exactly have a conciousness it doesn't exactly count as killing someone. I find it more dangerous is the attachment to the pleasure derived from the act of (oral) sex which leads to alot of akusala kamma, which leads to rebirth than the akusala kamma derived from the killing of sperm cells.